# Spring MVC version 4.2.5.RELEASE explicitly required HttpMessageConverter for application/json

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it required to add for Spring 4.2.5.RELEASE

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I was using older version of spring and not remember to adding this.
I am upgrading from 3.2.7 to 4.2.5 and found this.

Comment: You really shouldn't need to. Show us the rest of your context configuration.

Comment: I think I was missing <mvc:annotation-driven /> in my configuration. After adding it solved my probelm.

Comment: @Faraz thanks for all the description. but I was looking for xml configuration. which I figured out later.

Comment: @VijendraKulhade oh okay. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following HttpMessageConverters instances are pre-enabled by default in new releases of Spring MVC:

```
ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter – converts byte arrays
StringHttpMessageConverter – converts Strings
ResourceHttpMessageConverter – converts org.springframework.core.io.Resource  for any type of octet stream
SourceHttpMessageConverter – converts javax.xml.transform.Source
FormHttpMessageConverter – converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap<String, String>.
Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter – converts Java objects to/from XML (added only if JAXB2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson 2 is present on the classpath)
MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter – converts JSON (added only if Jackson is present on the classpath)
AtomFeedHttpMessageConverter – converts Atom feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
RssChannelHttpMessageConverter – converts RSS feeds (added only if Rome is present on the classpath)
```

OP further asked what viewResolver I am using. I think it is appropriate to show him all the message converters and viewResolver that I used.

```
@Inject ObjectMapper objectMapper;
@Inject Marshaller marshaller;
@Inject Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
@Inject SpringValidatorAdapter validator;
@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters
) {
converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter<>());
MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter =
new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();
xmlConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
new MediaType("application", "xml"),
new MediaType("text", "xml")
));
xmlConverter.setMarshaller(this.marshaller);
xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(this.unmarshaller);
converters.add(xmlConverter);
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter =
new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
jsonConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(
new MediaType("application", "json"),
new MediaType("text", "json")
));
jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(this.objectMapper);
converters.add(jsonConverter);
}
@Override
public void configureContentNegotiation(
ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer)
{
configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(false)
.ignoreAcceptHeader(false)
.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
{
return new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
}
}

 @Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE,
            false);
    return mapper;
}

@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller()
{
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "PACKAGE_NAME" });
    return marshaller;
}
```

Comment: I have Jackson2 added in my dependencies but some how it is not taking MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. Can you please tell me what is the View Resolver you are using?